# Firebase iOS 6.30.0 SDK Crash - GPBCreateMessageWithAutocreator

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-performance, adswizz

After updating to the latest [Firebase iOS SDK 6.30.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios) with [PerformanceMonitoring 3.3.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#performance-monitoring) using Cocoapods, I have started experiencing the following crash consistently across all iOS versions (iOS 9.0 - iOS 14.0), simulators/devices. The crash does not occur in the previous Firebase SDK 6.29.0 and below.

```
Thread 3 Queue : com.google.perf.FPREventsQueue (serial)
#0  0x000000010bae3080 in GPBCreateMessageWithAutocreator at /Users/ccaba/Projects/iOSAdswizzSDK/AdswizzSDK/AdswizzSDK/protobuf/GPBMessage.m:626
#1  0x000000010baa2b09 in GPBGetObjectIvarWithField at /Users/ccaba/Projects/iOSAdswizzSDK/AdswizzSDK/AdswizzSDK/protobuf/GPBUtilities.m:605
#2  0x000000010b949962 in FPRGetApplicationInfoMessage ()
#3  0x000000010b9496f3 in FPRGetPerfMetricMessage ()
#4  0x000000010b939477 in __22-[FPRClient logTrace:]_block_invoke ()
#5  0x000000010c379f11 in _dispatch_call_block_and_release ()
```

...
[image]

Comment: Would you ming raising an issue on Github with the stack trace and reproduction steps? Would like to take a look at this to resolve this.

Links for raising the Github issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues

Few things that might be helpful: Other dependencies (Podfile), stack trace and volume of crashes.

Comment: @Visu, I have filed a Firebase support ticket with Case 00078397. I have a sample Xcode project that reproduces this crash consistently upon launch. Happy to share that with you.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this has already been addressed.
Starting with the 6.23.0 release, FirebaseProtobufBinary must also be included.

ref: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Carthage.md

> Starting with the 6.23.0 release, if you're using FirebaseMessaging, FirebasePerformance, FirebaserRemoteConfig, FirebaseABTesting, FirebaseInAppMessaging, or FirebaseML, FirebaseProtobufBinary must also be included.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for your answer. Could you please complete your answerby directly quoting the relevant part of the page you linked? This will help your answer stay relevant in case the link breaks one day.

Comment: @Richard-Degenne
Thanks for the advice.
I added the quote.